# __get doesn't work twice for some name

Tags: php, yii, magic-methods

I know it's a strange setup but I'm trying to avoid some magic Yii so much loves.

```
class myActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function __get($name) {
        $method = 'get' . ucfirst($name);
        if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
            $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
            foreach($backtrace  as $b) {
                if($b['function'] == $method) {
                    return parent::__get($name);
                }
            }

            return $this->$method();
        }

        return parent::__get($name);
    }
}

class test extends myActiveRecords
{

    public function getParty()
    {
        return $this->party;
    }
}

$test = new test();
echo $test->party;
```

I would like it that if Yii calls $test->party it doesn't just look for the attribute but first goes through my getFunction() even if my getFunction just returns the attribute.
(in Yii the attributes are never defined as a property but always go through __get()

When I call $test->getParty() it works like a charm, however when Yii does this $test->party it does not, the following happens:

$this->party calls magic __get(), which calls the function getParty(). But then when the function getParty does again $this->party the magic function is not called a second time but I get an undefined property error.
I have a way around but I prefer not to use it and that's this function:

```
function getParty()
{
    return self::__get('party');
}
```

The reason I start to work like this is because I like get and set methods, I get shivers when I see public properties used like that and also because I'm stuck with legacy code that was not written in english so often I do this, which does work like a charm, just not when the magic function for the same name is called twice:

```
public function getParty()
{
    return $this->feest;
}
```

Does anyone know the reason? or am I just wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this could lead to infinite call to `__get()` method. Yes, you might put in some logic that would prevent it. But php chooses not to allow developers to shoot themselves in the foot. For this reason, once inside `__get()` method, it's not called again.

Comment: Here I was thinking PHP was all about shooting yourself in the foot.
But thank you for confirming that this is the way it should work according to PHP. I'll stick to my previous "solution" and call the __get method explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the magic `__get()`, you should do that in your child class like this:

```
class test extends myActiveRecords
{
    //overrides myActiveRecords' __get()
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name == 'party') return $this->$name;
        else return parent::__get($name);
    }
}
```

Check out the code based on the code you posted, that I think explains the difference: http://pastebin.com/cxh9HMah

Comment: the point is not to have to do that for every singly argument, then I prefer my "solution".